# How to align the Action bar Tab text in android

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

You can check out my output below.There you can see, In `ANNOUNCEMENT`,letter `T` is placed at bottom.It needs to be align like Gallery and placed in the center.

**styles.xml:**

```
<resources>


    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
         -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="GridLayout">
        <item name="android:drawSelectorOnTop">true</item>
        <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/photogrid_list_selector</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
        <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/custom_ratingbar</item>
         <item name="android:minHeight">20dip</item>
                <item name="android:maxHeight">20dip</item>
    </style>


    <style name="CustomTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme">
    <item name="android:tabWidgetStyle">@style/CustomTabWidget</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomTabWidget" parent="@android:style/Widget.TabWidget">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/CustomTabWidgetText</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomTabWidgetText" 
    parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget">
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
   <!--  <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item> -->
</style>


</resources>
```

I doesn't know how to solve these issue.Anybody can help me if you know how to solve these.Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I just tried it almost two days.But I can't find a solution for
  these.After that I think and solve these problem.
- Actually I am using an emulator.So that these kind of problems
  occurred for me.
- Then I try to run these code in `Real devices`.It seems Action bar
  Tab test `Announcement` align at the centre.Problem solved for me.